# What is a way to share a drop down inside a layout for use in all views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am becoming more familiar with MVC 3 and the RAZOR view engine. I have a question regarding layouts and shared controls on pages.

Let’s say I have a header section defined in my main layout. In that header is a dropdown I need to populate with project names. This dropdown will serve as a context for the entire site and is present on all pages. As an example, if the user selects “Project A” from the drop down, all of the views for the site will be based on “Project A”. Since this dropdown control is rather static and is used by the entire site, where is the best place to put the code to pull all the projects to display in the dropdown? In a Partial View? In a HTML helper?  Another thought is, if a user selects a new value, they would be taken to a dashboard or similar page for that newly selected project. I am trying to figure out how to reuse this control on every page in the site without having to keep wiring it up in every possible controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a child action along with the [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helper. So you start by defining a view model:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Project name")]
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProjectNames { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class ProjectsController: Controller
{
    private readonly IProjectsRepository _repository;
    public ProjectsController(IProjectsRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string projectId)
    {
        var projects = _repository.GetProjects();
        var model = new ProjectViewModel
        {
            ProjectId = projectId,
            ProjectNames = projects.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id,
                Text = x.Name
            })
        };
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

then the corresponding view (`~/views/projects/index.cshtml`):

```
@model ProjectViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProjectId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ProjectId, 
    Model.ProjectNames,
    new {
        id = "projects",
        data_url = Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")
    }
)
```

Now all that's left is to render this widget inside the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Products", new { projectid = Request["projectId"] })
```

And now we could put some javascript so that when the user decides to change the selection he is redirected to some other action:

```
$(function() {
    $('#projects').change(function() {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var projectId = encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
        window.location.href = url + '?projectid=' + projectId;
    });
});
```

Another possibility is to put the dropdown inside an HTML form:

```
@model ProjectViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProjectId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.ProjectId, 
        Model.ProjectNames,
        new {
            id = "projects",
        }
    )
}
```

so that inside the javascript we don't have to worry about building urls when the selection changes and simply trigger the containing form submission:

```
$(function() {
    $('#projects').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, this is the correct solution to rendering common HTML across all pages. Use Html.Action in your layout page, I can only suggest one more improvement : which is to use [OutputCache] with correct value on the action method called from Layout. It gives massive boost in rendering time.

Comment: @Darin  Is it  necessary to require a controller ? Can I have a HTML.helper method which will generates the dropdown ? For this approach , I need to write a separate controller and a view model. I just asking if I use an HTML Helper then, I can avoid this. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We just did a similiar thing on a project.

First, you can't really put it in a section because you have to put that section on every view, you could put it in a partial but you would still have to call it from every view.

Second, you can't really put it in the Layout page because the layout page isn't passed any kind of model.  So I created an html helper and referenced that in the layout page.  There are lots of tutorials on creating html helpers so I won't put the code here.  But essentially in your html helper you can make a database call to get all of your projects.  Then you can create a select list using string builder in the html helper and return that to the layout page.  We then used jquery to add an on change event to the select list.  When the select list changed it loaded a new page. So for example, in your select list the value of each item could be the project id, then on change it redirects them to a page like /Projects/View?id=234 where 234 is your project id.

So things to research.  1. Creating HTML Helpers 2. JQUERY change event.

That should get you in the right direction.  Let me know if you need any other help and I can post some code.